# can't connect spark and pycharm. please help me

Tags: python, apache-spark, pycharm, spark-shell

```
C:\Users\nowee>spark-shell
Python지정된 경로를 찾을 수 없습니다.

C:\Users\nowee>pyspark
Python지정된 경로를 찾을 수 없습니다.
지정된 경로를 찾을 수 없습니다.
```

When I first did pyspark and spark-shell with cmd, it worked, but suddenly this error popped up.
The environment settings are as follows.

```
%SCALA_HOME%bin
c:spark-3.1.2-bin0hadoop3.2\bin
%JAVA_HOME%\bin
%PyCharm%
%PyCharm Community Edition%

SCALA_HOME C:\scala
SPARK HOME C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2
```

I don't know what the hell is the problem.
Help.

Comment: This could help you `https://kaizen.itversity.com/setup-spark-development-environment-pycharm-and-python/`

Comment: StackOverflow is an English site, so we can't read your error message.

Comment: python
The specified path could not be found.

Comment: this is error message